# How to configure Compass module with Basic theme?

Tags: 7

I am trying to use compass framework with Drupal 7, Basic theme and Compass module on my local hosting on Windows. It is already installed on my computer.

Should i install it to my local webserver again somehow, how can i know the path of existing Compass exutable?

Comment: Have you tried the [Compass](http://drupal.org/project/compass) or [Compass Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush_compass) modules?  I'm not sure if they'll help at all hence the comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the only real answer i can give is set up a real webserver on Unix system with ruby (rails or without rails) and use whatever you want. I did not managed to get it running on windows. But ---- windows, lads